# Prolog checking the same fact twice

Tags: prolog

This is the knowledge database

```
student(jack,100,21,m).

takes(100,cs01).
takes(100,cs02).
takes(100,cs03).

teaches(doe,cs01).

course(cs01,ai).
course(cs02,cpp).
course(cs03,java).

isTaughtBy(Sname,Lname) :-
    teaches(Lname,Mcode),
    student(Sname,Scode,_,_),
    takes(Scode,Mcode).
```

When running isTaughtBy(jack,doe) it returns true (like its supposed to) and false (for some reason, probably because jack takes multiple modules).

This is the trace:

```
[trace]  ?- isTaughtBy(jack,doe).
Call: (8) isTaughtBy(jack, doe) ? creep
Call: (9) teaches(doe, _18526) ? creep
Exit: (9) teaches(doe, cs01) ? creep
Call: (9) student(jack, _18526, _18528, _18530) ? creep
Exit: (9) student(jack, 100, 21, m) ? creep
Call: (9) takes(100, cs01) ? creep
Exit: (9) takes(100, cs01) ? creep
Exit: (8) isTaughtBy(jack, doe) ? creep
true ;
Redo: (9) takes(100, cs01) ? creep
Fail: (9) takes(100, cs01) ? creep
Fail: (8) isTaughtBy(jack, doe) ? creep
false.
```

Why is it redoing takes(100,cs01) if it was already checked above? Why is it returning false even though its clearly defined in the database? What am i not understanding here? I just want it to return true or false if a student is taught by a lecturer on any of the modules they are taking.

Comment: Because you press semicolon. The first true is the result. `takes/2` has multiple clauses, but only one matches `cs01`. That is why you see a redo in the trace.

Comment: @TomasBy im trying to make it work so it only returns one value. is it possible?

Comment: Get another Prolog. Here is what Sictsus does: `?- isTaughtBy(jack,doe).
yes`

Comment: There may be a setting to control this behaviour also.

Comment: `once(isTaughtBy(jack,doe)).`